# How can I have multiple random outputs from a single line of code (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

How would I have a single line of code generate more than one random choice from a chosen list?

btw I do have `import random` at the top of the code

here is my code:

(R[0] = "RED", O[0] = "ORANGE", etc.)

```python
ColourList = [R[0],O[0],Y[0],G[0],B[0],I[0],V[0]]
ColourSeq = random.choice(ColourList)
print(ColourSeq)
```

I know at the moment I have only asked it to give me one output, but I would like it to be able to give me four of the items from `ColourList` in just one line of code.
There can be duplicate outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [random.choices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) instead of **random.choice**. It is new in version 3.6.

```
ColourList = [R[0],O[0],Y[0],G[0],B[0],I[0],V[0]]
ColourSeq = random.choices(ColourList, k=6)
print(ColourSeq)
```

Comment: nice.. i didn't knew about `random.choices`.. i guess i should delete my answer now :p

Answer (score 2):

If you want to allow duplicate values, you can't use `random.sample()`. You can use a list comprehension:

```
ColourList = [R[0],O[0],Y[0],G[0],B[0],I[0],V[0]]
ColourSeq = [random.choice(ColourList) for x in range(4)]
print(ColourSeq)
```

---

If you want to print those values on separate lines, without the various additions of the list, replace the `print` statement with

```
print(*ColourSeq, sep='\n')
```

or with the longer but clearer

```
for v in ColourSeq:
    print(v)
```

If you want them printed on the same line but with the list stuff removed, just use the simple

```
print(*ColourSeq)
```

Comment: Is there a way to remove the quotation marks, commas and square brackets from the answer?
@RoryDaulton

Comment: @matt6297: Do my additions answer the question in your comment?

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension:

```
import random
ColourList = [R[0],O[0],Y[0],G[0],B[0],I[0],V[0]]
new_colors = [random.choice(ColourList) for i in range(4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
size = 2  
colors = random.sample(ColourList, size)
```

Comment: `random.sample` samples without replacement. OP needs sampling with replacement.